# Not able to fetch the multiselect ids into array and inserting into database in codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

Hi i am using a multiselect dropdown for selecting the multiple categories multiselect is working fine but while printing in an array it is displaying only last id.Not getting all the selected records in an array.

View:

```
<div class="element">
        <label for="categoryname"><font color="black">Category Name</font></label>
        <?php
            $categorylist['']='--Select Category Name--';
            $category_id="id='category_id[]'  multiple='multiple' ";
            if($this->input->post('category_id')) $selected=$this->input->post('category_id');else $selected='';
            echo form_dropdown('category_id',$categorylist,$selected,$category_id);
        ?>
        <?php echo form_error('category_id', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?><br/><br/>     
    </div>
```

Model:

```
function insertblogs()
{
    $options = $this->input->post('category_id');
    $array = explode(",", $options);
    print_r($array);
    exit();
    $data=array(
    'category_id'=>$array,
    'blog_title'=>$this->input->post('blog_title'),
    'description'=>$this->input->post('description'),
    'position'=>$this->input->post('position')
    );
    $this->db->insert('blogs',$data);
```

Comment: use `form_multiselect `

Comment: Used form_multiselect it is not working getting only one id in array

Comment: Use this : `<?php echo form_multiselect('keywords[]', $keys); ?>`

Comment: but where you have declared $keys

Comment: getting error as 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: keys

Filename: views/blogs.php

Line Number: 121
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Line Number: 331

Comment: i am telling you the syntax ..... keywords refers to category_id and $keys refer to category array. Modify it acc to your requirements

Comment: In database it is inserting two times with category ids different i need to insert these category ids separated by comma

Comment: ofcourse why not it is an array. Use `implode` and before using update the code.

Comment: @HappyCoding Thank you very much its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model:

```
function insertblogs()
{
    $options = $this->input->post('category_id');
    $array = implode(",", $options);

    $data=array(
    'category_id'=>$array,
    'blog_title'=>$this->input->post('blog_title'),
    'description'=>$this->input->post('description'),
    'position'=>$this->input->post('position')
    );
     if ( $_FILES AND $_FILES['image_path']['name'])
            {
                $file_name = $this->do_upload2();
                if(is_array($file_name)){
                    $error['imageerror'] = $file_name['error'];
                }
                else
                $data['image_path']=$file_name;
            }
            if(!isset($data['image_path']) && !isset($error['imageerror']))

        $error['imageerror'] ="Please Upload an image";

    if(isset($error))return $error;
   print_r($data);
        $this->db->insert('blogs',$data);

   }
```

View:

```
<div class="element">
        <label for="categoryname"><font color="black">Category Name</font></label>
        <?php
            $categorylist['']='--Select Category Name--';
            $category_id="id='category_id[]'  multiple='multiple' ";
            if($this->input->post('category_id')) $selected=$this->input->post('category_id');else $selected='';
            echo form_multiselect('category_id[]',$categorylist,$selected,$category_id);

        ?>
        <?php echo form_error('category_id', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?><br/><br/>     
    </div>
```